# How to create multiple wiki pages in Bitbucket and see/edit them later?

Tags: bitbucket

I could create multiple wiki with '+new' link, but after creating it, there is no easy way to see this new page from repository home page. Only 'home' (default) wiki is available. Am I missing something ?

In github, this feature intuitive and pretty straight forward. You can see all you wiki pages with the 'pages' link.

Comment: Also moving from github to bitbucket, this is bizarre that you can't by default see the wikis you created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can more or less reproduce the "pages" page from github by replacing the text in the root page by the following:

```
<<toc / >>
```

Comment: I did this and now just see nothing on the home page.

Comment: @Jay This is possible if you have created no other pages.

Comment: Look at https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Adding+a+Table+of+Contents+to+a+Wiki for flavours other than Creole

Comment: You have to set the markup to be **creole** only for the Home (the page where the TOC will be)

Answer (score 2):

Though their does not appear to be a feature that lists all the created wiki pages on bitbucket, you could clone the wiki repository in order to view and edit each wiki page as a separate file. The command to clone a wiki is something like:

```
hg clone https://<user>@bitbucket.org/<user>/<project>/wiki
```

Answer (score 1):

**To create a wiki page**- In your bit bucket account firstly create a repository , after that inside your repository click on wiki link. you will see + create page button. click on it. and start writing your wiki page.

**To see your old wiki pages**- firstly select your repository , go to wiki link. then you see your repository name / Home. click on this repository name which is hyperlink to list of all wiki pages. here you can view your old wiki pages.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is currently broken. Follow Issue [BB-6368](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/5127/bug-with-wiki-toc-bb-6368) for the fix.

More information [here](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/5127/bug-with-wiki-toc-bb-6368)